# Style Rails Select Tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in rails with a select tag. I'm trying to style it like so:

```
<%= f.select :role, collection: User.roles.keys.to_a, class:"form-control form-control-lg" %>
```

I have tried the following:

```
<%= f.select :role, collection: User.roles.keys.to_a, {}, class:"form-control form-control-lg" %>
```

and

```
<%= f.select (:role, collection: User.roles.keys.to_a, class:"form-control form-control-lg") %>
```

But can't get the style to apply to the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following

```
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select(User.roles.keys.to_a, params[:role]), {}, class: 'form-control form-control-lg' %>
```

I think will help